# Double Tap to Zoom Feature for Map Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

I did this for MapView before and it was pretty simple czuse there were predefined methods like `onInterceptTouchEvent` or `GestureListeners` etc.

Did anyone try this double tap or double click zoom feature in Map Fragment as well. I googles  but still not able to found any solution.

i just started it by adding the UiSettings only `getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);`

Will it be implemented by the help of `setOnMapClickListener()` or something is there to handle the gesture for double tap event for Map Fragment ?

**NOTE: This question purely on MapFragment and not related to MapView which have already answers [Double tap: zoom on Android MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691235/double-tap-zoom-on-android-mapview)**

**EDIT**
MapFragment which I used in the layout:

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/noItemsText"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/storesListView"
            style="@style/Fill"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </ViewFlipper>
```

The class is a controller which is working for the Activity which extends Activity not AppCompactActivity.

Also I added marker clustering in the map.

Class side:

```
public class StoreFinderController extends BeeonicsControllerBase implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<AllClusterItems>,ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<AllClusterItems> {
```

onMapReady:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    /*better to work with our map :)*/
    this.googleMap = googleMap;

    mClusterManager = new CustomClusterManager<AllClusterItems>(getActivity(), getMap());
    getMap().setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnInfoWindowClickListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);

    /*map additional settings*/
    setUpMap();

    //setUpGoogleMap();
    //readItems();
}
```

And inside setUpMap I am simply transferring some data in between objects.

Comment: @King of Masses I clearly mention that its for Map Fragment not MapView. Please read the question properly before adding any duplicate tags.

Comment: Ok. reopened the question

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide more code (and XML)? I have an application with a `MapFragment` and the zoom just works "out of the box".

Comment: @MikeL I updated the question with some codes and xml..please free to ask anything.

Comment: @Ranjit are you able to get click listener and map object in your code?

Comment: @KaranMer I didn't get which clicklistener you are asking for. googleMap object I am able to get ..that `getmap()` method is returning the map object which I have written.

Comment: @Ranjit can you try to set OnDoubleTapListener to your fragment? it has ondouble tap method.

Comment: @KaranMer OnDoubleTapListener is not there unfortunately..Its for MapView but i am using MapFragment

Comment: it is interface, you can implement it to your fragment.

Comment: @Ranjit my thought was maybe there's another view that is intercepting the touch event, I've tried to add some of your code but it is still working for me

Comment: @Ranjit: if you can get hold of your map object you can zoom using `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());`, how you capture the event its upto you.

Comment: @MikeL Can you extend only Activity instead of AppCompact and check please

Comment: @KaranMer let me try that interface

Comment: @Ranjit my changes include changing to `Activity` (and using `fragmentManager`) - off topic: why don't you use the `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @MikeL Its an obstacle for me to change for the current project in which i am  working due to the lead unfortunately. Anyways I need to check why its not coming. will update you soon

Comment: @Ranjit : did you checked it?

Comment: @KaranMer i still not able to understand how to start. if I implement the interface to my class then all override methods will come like doubleTp and onTouch.. etc..then what ?

Comment: are you able to get your map object in fragment? if yes, then in your desired event you can use `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());`

Comment: @KaranMer I did it but how to link the interface..like getMap().doubleClick or somthing like this

Comment: @Ranjit: are you able to get your map object in your fragment? there will be `onDoubleTapEvent()` write `map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());` in it.

Comment: @KaranMer Yes I can see onDoubleTap is there and I wrote also these zoonin stuffs..I implemented the DoubleTap interface and add your code in onDoubleTap event..is that all ? I need to all something to link that interface event to my map right same like how we are doing for onClick i.e getMap().setOnClickListener(this) etc

Comment: map.animate camera will do it. debug and check whether your event is being received

Comment: if you are not able to get event, check solution here to set gesture listener to view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054908/how-to-add-a-gesture-detector-to-a-view-in-android

Comment: did you try [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487485/capture-double-tap-from-map-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried all possible solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054908/how-to-add-a-gesture-detector-to-a-view-in-android) and [here](https://dimitar.me/how-to-detect-a-user-pantouchdrag-on-android-map-v2/) in which they have given some other ways to handle the double tap by the help of the touch event. But unfortunately nothing worked for me.

So I ended with the predefined `onMapClickListener()` which calls on a single click of the map.  I pasted my solution below:

```
 getMap().setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
    });
```

Anyways thanks [Karan Mer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629397/karan-mer) for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Have You tried to set your listener onMapReady() call back? and then set**

**mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);**

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
 mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                try {


                //   mMap.clear();
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Vaibhav, I don't think any settings will work. I hope there should be something like  method or listener which will handle the double click/tap in MapFragment. setZoomGesturesEnabled might be the flag to kick start.

Comment: Lets see..  need to dig deeper.
Code which i have  working properly.
I will check again Sir , Thank you